# Disabling autocapitalize for a contenteditable div within a UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which loads a basic html page with a contenteditable div. This div has the following attributes:

```
<div id="editor" 
     contenteditable="true" 
     autocapitalize="none" 
     autocorrect="off" 
     autocomplete="off">#CONTENT#</div>
```

However, in iOS 5 and iOS 6, sentences are still being capitalized.

I've tried setting `autocapitalize` to `off`, but then set it to `none` as per the [Safari HTML Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html), but still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autocapitalize`, `autocorrect`, `autocomplete` are supported input and form tags only. See `Related Tags` in the doc.